# Minimal Fron End Web Appication with Secure External API Consumption

Tags: api, vue.js

**Problem requirement**

Web application with a text field and a button. After introducing some text and clicking on the button, the web application shall call an API using credentials which should be invisible/inaccessible to the web user or its browser. This external API will take the input text an store it into a DB to which it is connected.

Unfortunately the API I need to call contains username and password inside the URL, so that they are visible to the browser.

API Login URL has this profile
`https://apidomain/service/login/{{username}/{{password}}`

**Question**

It is there a way to do this only using front end frameworks (vue, react) or static web sites without having to host a back-end service (to perform this external API call)?

I tried this with vuejs 3 successfully, but API call is browser visible.

Comment: When the browser sends the request you cannot hide it. Every HTTP call can be viewed inside the browser. Why would that be a problem, they known their own credentials right? The credentials are encrypted by TLS in transit

Comment: This external API call uses credentials which shall not be public for the user. The user do not know this credentials and shall not see them

Comment: This will require a backend service such as an backend api, serverless function or API gateway. You cannot hide the data in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [auth0](https://auth0.com) it provides fast solution

As far as I know there is no way to hide data except you need back-end auth0 is fast solution
but you might use hash function
hashed = f(username+password) so the user knows the hashed but he couldn't figure what's the username and password it's one way function